# ICP 3D scan matching algorithms

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am looking for latest scan matching algorithms based on ICP, implemented for 3D case in ROS. Can you give me some examples? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297922/icp-3d-scan-matching-algorithms/) by [alias](https://answers.ros.org/users/36549/alias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-07-19**:
There are many point cloud libraries out there that have support for ICP, and most of these could easily be integrated into a ROS application. PCL is an obvious choice, and I've lately had good luck with [Open3D](https://github.com/IntelVCL/Open3D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the point cloud library (PCL) is included with ROS for these types of task. It has a full implementation of the ICP algorithm, with a [tutorial here](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/interactive_icp.php).

If you can tell us more about your application including how you're acquiring the 3D information then we may be able to give you a more specific answer.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0